# Read messages from specific forum (group) topic using telethon v1

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I am working on a project and I would like **to fetch first 10 messages from a specific group topic** in telegram, unfortunately I can't find any way for this in documentation.
I am using telethon `1.30.3`.

I've tried to use standard `TelegramClient.get_enitty` for this with a direct link to forum topic `channel = await client.get_entity('https://t.me/ddostup/1118')`, but telethon failed to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

simply to do it you can follow up my code :
Make sure you create a APP in the dev section and repalce the app_id  as well api_hash

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from loguru import logger


# Replace YOUR_API_ID and YOUR_API_HASH with the values from your Telegram API
api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
channelsNames = ["prdscloud"]
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    for channel_username in channelsNames:
        try:
            logger.info("Checking for logs in channel:  " + channel_username)
            messages = await client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=10, offset_id=0)
            if not messages:
                break
            logger.info("Found " + str(len(messages)) + " messages.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
    print("All messages have been fetched.")

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution lays in internal implementation of topics by telegram.
Topics are implemented as message threads, so all messages in group(forum) topic have `reply_id` being set to topic id

Thus this code will iterate over all messages in a group topic

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reply_to=topic_id, limit=10)
```